# Transpose matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T: V\to W$ be a linear transformation and let {$v_1,...,v_n$}, {$w_1,...,w_m$} be  ordered basis of $V$ and $W$ then

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}w_1+a_{12}w_2+\cdots+a_{1m}w_m=T(v_1) \\ 
a_{21}w_1+a_{22}w_2+\cdots+a_{2m}w_m=T(v_2) \\
\vdots \\ 
a_{n1}w_1+a_{n2}w_2+\cdots+a_{nm}w_m=T(v_n) \\ 
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$

For me the "natural" way to define the matrix of the transformation $T$ would be:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1m} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nm} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

but instead we work with the transpose of the matrix, but why? Can someone please clarify this to me?

Comment: It's to do with whether you multiply by a column matrix (on the right) or a row matrix (on the left).